# Automatically add a scroll in Multiline when the number of rows is exceeded

Tags: scrollbar, multiline, pysimplegui

Tell me how to automatically connect scrolling in PySimpleGUI Multiline when the number of lines entered exceeds. For example, to enable scrolling when there are more than 5 lines

`sg.Multiline(size=(42, 5))`

Comment: `sg.Multiline(size=(42, 5), autoscroll=True, key='-DETAILS-')`
does not work. Scroll appears immediately, when the field is empty

Comment: posted the code below with an example of a display window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is to hack the method `set` for the `tk.Scrollbar`, and it is only work for the vertical scrollbar for following code.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def scrollbar_set(self, lo, hi):
    if float(lo) <= 0.0 and float(hi) >= 1.0:
        self.pack_forget()
    elif self.cget("orient") != sg.tk.HORIZONTAL:
        self.pack(side=sg.tk.RIGHT, fill=sg.tk.Y)
    self.old_set(lo, hi)

sg.tk.Scrollbar.old_set = sg.tk.Scrollbar.set
sg.tk.Scrollbar.set     = scrollbar_set

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Auto hide scrollbar', size=25)],
    [sg.Multiline(size=(20, 5), expand_x=True, expand_y=True, key='-ML-')]]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def begin_window():
    layout = [[sg.Multiline(size=(42, 5), autoscroll=True)]]

    # Create the Window
    window = sg.Window('Title', layout)
    # window['-INDEX-'].bind("<Return>", "_Enter")
    # Event Loop to process "events" and get the "values" of the inputs
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()

        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == '-CANCEL-':  # if user closes window or clicks cancel
            break

    window.close()

    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    begin_window()
```

Scroll appears immediately, when the field is empty
[image]